# How to check whether a pdf file has 3d content using metadata?

Tags: java, pdf, 3d

I am trying to differentiate normal pdf files from 3dpdf files in java using the metatag of the files.I dont find any attribute which gives this information.

Had anyone tried this before.

Thanks

Comment: What all you did please show that code as well then someone can able to help you?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the metadata of the PDF file?  This is definitely where I would start working on this problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes i tried to check the metadata of both normal and 3dpdf files using http://www.extractmetadata.com .But i could not find anything specific to 3dPDF rendering

Comment: @Althaf According to the PDF spec *3D annotations (PDF 1.6) are the means by which 3D artwork shall be represented in a PDF document.* Thus, the presence of 3D content need not be indicated in PDF metadata, you have to parse the PDF format in search for such annotations.